# Increase width for fixed height HTML table data cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

A similar question like [Fixed Height and Changing Width for Header (HTML Table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978592/fixed-height-and-changing-width-for-header-html-table) - except I'd like to ask: is there a different way to achieve this, other than using `&nbsp;` instead of space? Basically, I'd like increasing text content in the table data cell to keep the cell height fixed, and instead increase the cell width..

Below is a minimal HTML example, which behaves like this upon changing the browser (Firefox 43) width:

[image: animate-browser.gif]

As you can see, regardless of `height`/`max-height` specification in CSS, the table `td` fields increase their height, while decreasing the width.

What I'd like to happen is in this case, the specified height - and the corresponding width - of `td` cells remains the same upon change of browser width, and what changes instead is the bottom scrollbar.

Is there any way I could achieve this with CSS, or even JS?

---

In response to [@tgallimore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36765598/6197439)'s questions:

- *Are you able to give a fixed width to the table?* - no, I'd like it to resize width depending on content
- *Do you know how wide you would like each cell to remain?* - no, I'd like it to have a fixed width, then if it's enough for two rows of text, these should be adjusted for optimal width (i.e. each row has approximately the same amount of text)
- Can this width be given to each cell? - no, cells would have differing text contents, as in the example

In response to  [@Leothelion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36765631/6197439)'s post: I wanted to specify a fixed height of `2em` (or let's say, `2.5em`), is because I'd expect it to allow enough vertical space for max two lines of text. So what I want to achieve is: 
* If the text in the cell is short (i.e. one word), then there's no line breaking, text is in single line, and cell height is `2.5em`
* If the text in the cell is long (a whole sentence), then I'd want the layout to figure out that the in a cell height of `2.5em` it can fit max two lines of text; thereafter it would try to break the text such that there are approximately the same amount of characters in both lines (so now we have a "paragraph"; and finally it would set the width of the cell to the width of this newly line-broken "paragraph".

In other words, I would like this layout:

[image: ffox-tab-layout.png]

... regardless of how I scale the browser width; if the browser width is too small, then only the horizontal scrollbar adjusts.

---

The sample HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
.mytbl,
.mytbl tr th,
.mytbl tr td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  font: 12px helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
}
.mytbl tr td {
  height: 2em;
  max-height: 2em;
}
.mtytblwrap {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #000;
  padding: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
ondocready = function() {
  // placeholder - nothing for now...
}
$(document).ready(ondocready);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <div id="wrapper1" class="mtytblwrap">
    <table id="table1" class="mytbl">
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th> Dendrologist </th>
         <th> Iciness </th>
         <th> JoyfulDistortion </th>
         <th> Suburbicarian </th>
         <th> Ecballium </th>
         <th> AbulicNonviolence </th>
         <th> GrowlerTheocracy </th>
         <th> Necessitattion </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td> A1 </td>
         <td> Just testing some longer content here, so long that it might not fit on a single line </td>
         <td> Molybdenum </td>
         <td> D1 </td>
         <td> Scanty Distensibility </td>
         <td> Arithmetical </td>
         <td> G1 </td>
         <td> Hypallelomorph </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you able to give a fixed width to the table?
Do you know how wide you would like each cell to remain? Can this width be given to each cell?

A table-cell will ALWAYS expand its height if it's content doesn't fit, regardless of wether you set a height or not (so a `height` in this case would work as a `min-height`).

Also, you will probably need to use `.mytbl { table-layout: fixed; }`. This tells the table to use the widths that you have defined, rather than try to fix it's content in each cell. See this for more info: https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Comment: Thanks for that, @tgallimore - I have updated the OP with answers to our questions; I will definitely take a look at `table-layout: fixed;` and the link you sent. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

What you need is  **Media query**

See my [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/pqj8obyp/5/)

On different resolution(i just took 1, adjust according to your need ), fixed the width and `table-layout: fixed;` and you will get your solution.

Comment: Many thanks for that @Leothelion - but as far as I can see, your fiddle does not fix the cell height to say 2em, what it does instead is fix the table width, and then sets each cell to have an equal share of the width -- which is an interesting solution, but not exactly what I'm looking for... Cheers!

Comment: oohh..sorry if its not give you perfect answer :(

Comment: No problem, @Leothelion - it's still good to have a reference to the solution you posted; cheers!

Comment: Thanks again, @Leothelion - the reason why I wanted to specify a height of 2em, is that I'd expect there is enough vertical space for the text to be broken into two lines (and two lines maximum); what happens on your fiddle is that you've used `nowrap`, so even if the td cell has the right height, the text is only one line. I updated my OP with a clarification.